# How to invoke REST API endpoint response using HTML form submit GET method with jQuery AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, get, endpoint

I have a web service endpoint created for me located on a different server other than my website. The endpoint provides two success responses 200 OK and 201 CREATED as well as three error responses 400 BAD, 403 FORBIDDEN and 500 SERVER ERROR.

The form is executing the endpoint with the GET method and form action is the endpoint. I actually will have multiple forms and endpoints on one page but starting with one form first to try and get working.

I have a form located below that when a number is typed in and submitted the web-service is used to validate that number and return one of the responses. There is an email field and is used for record keeping.

```
<form id="myForm" method="get" action="http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/xxxx.svc/xxxx? 
upgradePathId=1&licenseCode={{license}}&email={{email}}" target="_parent"" >
<input type="hidden" name="upgrade" value="1">
<input type="text" name="email" size='35'>
<input type="text" name="license" size='35'>
<input type="submit" name="submit"> 
</form>

<div id="display-data"></div>
```

So far with just the form and endpoint I am getting the success or error responses correctly, but on the other wcf server. I just want them to display in place of the form or in a div below the form?

I have tried using jQuery ajax snippets but those call for the endpoint in the code when I will have multiple endpoints for multiple forms on the same web page. I cannot get the data to display on the same page as form.

Is there ajax code that can be used here to display REST endpoint validation data after form submit?